# Are there any "secret" rooms that contain cube bits?

Tags: fez

OK. I have 31 cubes, and 7 bits. There is one missing. Where in the world is it hidden?

Before you say, "That's impossible to answer without knowing all the other ones you've already collected" there are a few relevant bits of information:

- Going through as if this were my first play-through:

  - Not exploring any secret areas
  - Avoiding all anti-cubes, even the more obvious ones
- With the exception of secret doors:

  - All rooms on my map are gold
  - All non-secret paths have been thoroughly explored

---

<sub>*Why am I going through the game this way? Because it's fun! During my first play-through a few years ago, much was left unexplored since enough stray anti-cubes were collected to finish the game without exploring everything.*</sub>

---

Given all that, the real question is:

**Is there a secret room somewhere with a cube bit in it?**

Comment: I don't think the editorial italics adds much to this question, especially the jab at the reader.  An otherwise good question and answer that might get downvotes it doesn't deserve.

Comment: @EBongo Point taken. Question edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the owls. You must find the four owls, and enter their secret room, that has one cube bit, and also an anti-cube.

This is the **only** secret room in the game that has a regular cube bit inside it.

*This seems like the designer's way of ensuring that everyone who completes the game is, at the very least, aware of the existence of anti-cubes.*

[image: owl secret room on the world map]

[image: owl secret room detail]

Comment: I should have been tipped off by this earlier, as a comment on another question mentioned that finding the owls was required (and apparently required for the first play-through, assuming you don't stumble on any anti-cubes).